# Creating a boolean method with 3 parameters (String, int [non-negative], double [positive only])

Tags: java, methods, parameters

"A boolean method called originalStockUp that takes a product name (String), count of product now in stock [int must be non-negative], and marketValue of each product [double- positive only] as parameters. This method sets all the class variables properly upon call and returns a true unless the stock-room had previously been stocked for the first time. (i.e. this method returns a false if this method had previously been called.)" (Can not use class variable names as parameters).

For what I was given in quotations I need to set up a method header. I wasn't sure how to set the parameters so that int is a non-negative, and double is positive only.

What I thought of:

```
public static boolean originalStockUp(String, int, double)
```

Here are my variables (outside of the methods):

```
static int countOfProduct = -1;
    static String productName = "Not set yet.";
    static double marketValuePer = 0.0;
    final static String MY_NAME = "Name";
```

Here is my main method if this helps any:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        showStock();

        if (!originalStockUp("Yoyo", 500, 4.75))
            reportErrorAndBomb("First call to stock up failed. Why?");
        showStock();

        if (originalStockUp("Pen", 1500, 1.01))
            reportErrorAndBomb("Second call to stock up succeded. Why?");

        if (stockCount() != 500)
            reportErrorAndBomb("Inventory count is now off. (500)");

        if (addStock(-100))
            reportErrorAndBomb("You let me add -100?? Why?");

        if (! addStock(100))
            reportErrorAndBomb("Adding 100 failed. Why?");

        if (getValue() != 4.75)
            reportErrorAndBomb("How did our product value get off? ($4.74)");

        setValue(4.85); //Inflation...

        if (getValue() != 4.85)
            reportErrorAndBomb("How did our product value get off? ($4.85)");

        if (inventoryBalance() != 2910.00)
            reportErrorAndBomb("Hmm issue with value of full inventory?");

        if (stockCount() != 600)
            reportErrorAndBomb("Inventory count is now off. (600)");

        showStock();

        //Just test the error reporter code.
        reportErrorAndBomb("Bye bye - all actually went well!");

    }//End Method: Main

}//End class: Program 4.
```

First time having to write a method that isn't main. Sorry if the question is too vague or basic.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That's right. Just give names to the parameters, and put code in the braces.

Comment: are you using Java 8?

Comment: It would actually be good to supply names for those parameters. Types alone won't work like that.

Comment: @Matt for what I was given in quotations I need to set up a method header. I wasn't sure how to set the parameters so that int is a non-negative, and double is positive only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wasn't sure how to set the parameters so that int is a non-negative, and double is positive only.

You can't enforce that kind of constraint in the method signature in Java.  (There are one or two programming languages that support types with range constraints ... but it is not a main-stream language feature.)

What you should do is add some code inside the method to *validate* the parameters it is called with, at runtime, and throw an exception if a range constraint is violated.  For example:

```
if (param < 42) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("param is too small: " + param);
}
```

(In theory, you could use `assert` instead of explicitly testing / throwing.  However, assertion checking is disabled by default, and you typically don't want it to be possible to "turn off" validation of inputs.)

Answer (score 0):

That is partially correct, you should also name the parameters. If your question is how to access it from the main method, you can just do this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    String firstitem = "Candy";
    int numfirstitem = 10;
    double pricefirstitem = 1.39;
                                       //name   , stock       , price
    boolean question = originalStockUp(firstitem, numfirstitem, pricefirstitem);
    if(question == true){
         System.out.println("true");
    }else{
         System.out.println("false");
    }
    //this will return true or false based on what you do in the method
}

public static boolean originalStockUp(String name, int stock, double price){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java it would be:

```
boolean originalStockUp(String productName, int countInStock, double marketValue) {
    // ... code goes here
}
```

And then to execute the method you would use it like that:

```
boolean outcome = originalStockUp("The_Product", 17, 57.93);
```

`public` and `static` are not mandatory and they got additional meaning. Public makes method accessible for other classes: [docs on `public`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/public). Static makes it not require an instance: [docs on `static`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/static).